# DataGridView.Rows.Clear: System.NullReferenceException in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Again, This is my situation.
Basically, i want clear rows and add rows every certain time. My simplest code follows:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
            Dim wreturnCode1 As Integer = System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf RepeatAction), cancellation.Token)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RepeatAction(ByVal obj As Object)
        Dim token As System.Threading.CancellationToken = CType(obj, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
        FormTimer.Enabled = True
        AddHandler FormTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf AutoTaskRepo
   End Sub

   Private Async Sub AutoTaskRepo()

        FormTimer.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        FormTimer.Enabled = True

   End Sub
```

In the datagridview i have 5 columns. When i add the rows, wait n seconds and clear the rows and add again the rows.

[Here is the table in the first iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCexd.jpg)

Next iterations works fine but in some moment after clear the rows the system throws me a `NullReferenceException`.

Note that i don't need datasource and datatable. I want to add manually and clear manually the data in the datagridview. SomeHelp

Comment: Maybe are threads that are origin the problem?

Comment: Use a WinForms Timer.

Comment: Thanks you very much! :D